# How do I remove/delete a (possibly corrupt) partition from macOS High Sierra?

Tags: macos, terminal, disk-utility, partition

I have a partition (disk0s2) I can't seem to get rid of. The size is very tiny around ~3KB. Disk Utility is unable to remove/erase or repair this partition. Also, the '-' button seems to be disabled. Can anyone help me with a terminal command to get rid of the partition? [image] [image]
[image]

Comment: You can’t remove (or edit) a partition from a disk that’s mounted.  You have to do this in Recovery or from a macOS booted from a different drive (like USB).  **What makes you think it’s corrupt?**. Do you know what’s on it?  Did you make a backup of your drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using the command:

```
diskutil eraseVolume "Free Space" %noformat% disk0s2
```